# Dúvida - Update SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-server-2012

Quando o update abaixo é executado pela primeira vez, o campo sai corretamente na forma que eu quero como está abaixo, porém, se eu o executo novamente, ele sai dessa forma. O que eu quero é que independente de quantas vezes for executado o script, não duplique o mês e nem o ano.

> **(ERRADO)**
>   Esttartitulo 
>   Produção Assistida EstratégicoOutubro-2017Outubro-2017
>
> **(CORRETO)**
>   Esttartitulo
>   Produção Assistida EstratégicoOutubro-2017

**Script de atualização**

```
UPDATE EstoqueTarefa
SET EstTarTitulo = (SELECT CONCAT(EstTarTitulo,DATENAME(MONTH,getdate()),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,getdate()))) 
WHERE EstTarID = 246
```

Comment: Você não pode adicionar uma coluna que indique que o título está atualizado?

Comment: não,não @Sorack

Comment: Dê um exemplo dos dados com pelo menos 2 registros e como eles ficarão após cada `update`. Está impossível de entender o que você quer pela descrição atual

Comment: @Sorack, vamos lá, abaixo é o exemplo de um registro sem o update na tabela estoquetarefa no campo esttartitulo
Exemplo sem o update

EstTarTitulo
Producao Assistida Estratégico

Exemplo logo após o update sendo executado no mes de outubro, é para ficar assim:

EstTarTitulo
Producao Assistida Estratégico NOVEMBRO - 2017

Exemplo logo após o update sendo executado no mes de novembro, é para ficar assim:

EstTarTitulo
Producao Assistida Estratégico DEZEMBRO - 2017

E assim por diante.

Comment: @Sorack, consegui resolver por aqui meu caro. Obrigado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare uma tabela de apoio, popule-a e utilize-a para verificar se o título já possui um mês incluído:

```
DECLARE @meses TABLE(numero INT,
                     nome   VARCHAR(10));
DECLARE @data_base DATE,
        @mes       VARCHAR(10),
        @ano       INT;

SET @data_base = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE());

INSERT INTO @meses
VALUES(1, 'JANEIRO'),
      (2, 'FEVEREIRO'),
      (3, 'MARÇO'),
      (4, 'ABRIL'),
      (5, 'MAIOR'),
      (6, 'JUNHO'),
      (7, 'JULHO'),
      (8, 'AGOSTO'),
      (9, 'SETEMBRO'),
      (10, 'OUTUBRO'),
      (11, 'NOVEMBRO'),
      (12, 'DEZEMBRO');

SELECT @mes = m.nome,
       @ano = DATEPART(YEAR, @data_base)
  FROM @meses m
 WHERE m.numero = DATEPART(MONTH, @data_base);

UPDATE et
   SET et.EstTarTitulo = EstTarTitulo + ' ' + @mes + ' - ' + CAST(@ano AS VARCHAR)
  FROM EstoqueTarefa et
 WHERE EstTarID = 246
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM @meses m
                   WHERE et.EstTarTitulo LIKE '%' + m.nome + '%')
```

Comment: ocorreu o erro de sintaxe: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '@mes'.

Comment: agora deu Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Falha ao converter o nvarchar valor 'Produção Assistida Estratégico OUTUBRO - ' para o tipo de dados int. E eu não consegui verificar onde.

Comment: blz, nao deu o erro, mas como eu to em outubro, gerei normalmente o mes de novembro, porém, fiz um teste colocando a data do servidor pra novembro para ver se geraria o de dezembro e nao gerou. OBS: lá no m.numero eu coloquei o date add para renomear o titulo pro mes seguinte. DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,1,getdate()));

Comment: @RenanBessa aí que está o erro. Se você queria o mês seguinte poderia ter dito isso na pergunta. Vou alterar para esta nova informação.

Comment: @RenanBessa alterei com essa nova informação.

Comment: @Sorack.meu jovem, testei aqui usando o mes de novembro para ver se geraria o titulo para dezembro, porém, nao atualizou, ficou o mesmo titulo de novembro.

Comment: @RenanBessa não entendi o teste que você fez. Você atualizou primeiro em novembro e depois em dezembro? Você quer que cada vez que rode mude o mês?

Comment: nao, assim: Estamos no mes de outubro certo? e quando gerar esse script do mes de outubro, o titulo vai para Producao Estrategico Novembro. Até ai gerou normalmente. Então fui testar como se eu estivesse no mes de novembro(alterando a data do servidor para novembro) para que o titulo mudasse para Producao Estrategico Dezembro, porém, nao gerou o titulo, ficou o mesmo titulo do mes anterior, no caso Novembro.

Comment: @RenanBessa Então o mesmo registro vai mudar o nome de outubro para novembro?

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer assim também

```
declare @MesAno varchar(50);
set @MesAno = (SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,getdate()) + '-' + Convert(varchar, DATEPART(YEAR,getdate())) as MesAno)

UPDATE  EstoqueTarefa
SET     EstTarTitulo = EstTarTitulo + @MesAno
WHERE   EstTarID = 246 AND CharIndex(@MesAno, EstTarTitulo)) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

O [charindex](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) deve resolver seu problema:

```
declare @MesAno varchar(50)
select @MesAno = CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,getdate()),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,getdate()))
select @MesAnoAnterior = CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())))

UPDATE EstoqueTarefa
SET EstTarTitulo = (SELECT CONCAT(REPLACE(EstTarTitulo,CONCAT(' ', @MesAnoAnterior),''), ' ', @MesAno)) 
WHERE EstTarID = 246
```

Assim ele só atualiza a coluna caso ela não contenha o que você quer adicionar. Como a proposta é que o *script* seja executado mensalmente, você pode utilizar a estrutura acima, onde:

- `REPLACE(EstTarTitulo,CONCAT(' ', @MesAnoAnterior),'')` remove do título o mês anterior (caso exista)
- `(SELECT CONCAT({resultadoDoReplace}, ' ', @MesAno))` atualiza o valor do título com o mês atual

Comment: ôpa grande @rLinhares, ocorreu o seguinte erro: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Uma expressão de tipo não booleano especificada em um contexto no qual se espera uma condição, próximo a ','.

Comment: Outra coisa r@Linhares, caso eu queira executar esse update em outros meses, eu nao queria q ficasse repetindo o mes anterior + mes atual, queria que por exemplo em novembro, ficasse da seguinte forma:Esttartitulo Produção Assistida Estratégico Novembro-2017, e não repetindo o mes de outubro.

Comment: @RenanBessa, corrigi o erro que você citou, foi mal :P agora vamos pensar na solução genérica que você possa rodar todo mês..

Comment: você vai rodar todo mês? porque uma saída seria remover o do mês anterior (quando existir) e adicionar o mês atual.

Comment: sim meu grande, irá rodar todo mes. E como seria mais ou menos? To enrolado, rsrs

Comment: @RenanBessa, veja se agora resolve..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67204/discussion-between-renan-bessa-and-rlinhares).

Comment: eu fiz o teste aqui e assim. Simulei os meses de outubro, novembro e dezembro. O de novembro gerou normalmente, porém, quando fui gerar a de dezembro, gerou dessa forma. 'Produção Assistida Estrategico Novembro 2017-Dezembro 2017'. Ou seja, não tirou o de novembro, mas o de novembro tirou o de outubro

Comment: @RenanBessa, fiz uns testes aqui.. acho que o erro ta só no charindex do final.. da uma testada novamente. E avisa porque se resolver preciso mudar a explicação da resposta :P

Comment: Dessa forma se ele rodar o script por 3 meses seguidos o mesmo erro ocorrerá.

Comment: @rLinhares, nesse caso vi q tu tirou o charindex, mas o erro de duplicação voltou.